# using CSVWriter to export database tables with BLOB

Tags: java

I've already tried exporting my database tables to CSV using the CSVWriter.

But my tables contain BLOB data. How can I include them in my export?

Then later on, im going to import that exported CSV using CSVReader. Can anyone share some concepts?

This is a part of my code for export

```
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("select * from "+db+"."+obTableNames[23]);

int colunmCount = getColumnCount(res);

try {
   File filename = new File(dir,""+obTableNames[23]+".csv");
   fw = new FileWriter(filename);


   CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(fw);
   writer.writeAll(res, false);
   int colType = res.getMetaData().getColumnType(colunmCount);  
   dispInt(colType);
   fw.flush();
   fw.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you take a look at [`encodeBase64String(byte[] data`)](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte%5B%5D%29) method from the [`Base64`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) provided by Apache?

> Encodes binary data using the base64 algorithm but does not chunk the output.

This should allow you to return encoded strings representing your Binary Large Object and incorporate it in your CSV.

People on the other side can then use the [`decodeBase64String(String data)`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28java.lang.String%29) to get the BLOB back again.